# When to return a value or use getter in a class in java

Tags: java, return-value, getter

I have a class that reads a file into a format I want:

```
public class ProgramReader {

    public List<String> readFromFile(String path){
        List<String> commands = null;
        try {
            commands = Files.lines(Paths.get(getClass().getResource(path).toURI()))
                    .map(line -> line.split("\\s+")).flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());;
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return commands;

    }
}
```

I am passing the path as a parameter (instead of passing through constructor) because, i dont want to instantiate every time i change the path. But I am confused as about returning the result ? Should i store it into a class member and then use getter method to access the result ? Or is this class efficient ?

Comment: It depends. What you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I don't see any problems with it, other than the fact that the method doesn't seem to relate to the instance (which is more of a personal dislike rather than an actual flaw). As for storing it in a field var, that depends on what your app requires

Comment: I wanted to know if this actually applies to the OO concept. Here I am just encapsulating a function. But is that ok ?

Answer (score 1):

From the code example you provided, there should be no problem in returning the value without saving it - provided you don't have to access the same value several times. If you do have to access the same value several times it may indeed be a good idea to save the result.

Basically I can see three ways in which this can go:

1. You (normally) don't need to access the same value more than once. Don't save the result and maybe even make the method `static`.
2. You often have to access the last value. In that case, save it to a private member and add a getter.
3. You often have to access prior results, though not necessarily the last result. Also, the method is agnostic (= same input always leads to same output) or if it isn't that's irrelevant. Then save the results to a `Map` with the path as the key.

Answer (score 0):

Here, every time `readFromFile` is called, the files is actually read.

An other option is to keep the result in order not to read the file again if the method is called several times:

```
public class ProgramReader {

    private String path;
    private List<String> words = null;

    public ProgramReader(String path) {
        super();
        this.path = path;
    }

    public List<String> getWords() {
        if(words == null) {
            words = readFromFile();
        }
        return words;
    }

    private List<String> readFromFile() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Do I have to pass path through constructor. Then wouldnt i have to instantiate a new object everytime the path changes ?

Comment: Yes you will have to. The words are associated to a specific path.